# How to register a DLL C# COM Interop BouncyCastle.dll also used in Windows 64bit?

Tags: c#, dll, cmd, vb6, 64-bit

I have a dll made in C# that uses Bouncycastle and which in turn is made to function in a Visual Basic 6 of 32 bits, so it has enabled the option  "COM INTEROP". I have tested it on Windows 32-bit and working properly.

The steps I follow to register in cmd line are:

1 step:

```
csc /target:module /reference:BouncyCaste.dll myDLLCOM.cs
```

2 step:

```
sn -k sign.pfx
```

3 step:

```
al /out:myDLLCOM.dll myDLLCOM.netmodule /keyfile:sign.pfx
```

4 step:

```
gacutil /i BouncyCastle.dll
```

5 step:

```
regasm /codebase /tlb:myDLLCOM.tlb myDLLCOM.dll
```

My problem is trying to register in a 64-bit windows. When my VB6 application in Win64 bits tries to create the object gives me "Error 429 ActiveX control can not create object.

**UPDATE: I tried to register with cmd, regasm and all command located in sysWOW64 folder and nothing.**

Anyone know what could be the problem?

Thank you for readme and sorry for my English! ;-)

Comment: But what _is_ the problem? Do you get an error? What does it say?

Comment: Yes, when my VB6 application tries to create the object gives me "Error 429 ActiveX control can not create object"

Comment: There are two versions of Regasm.exe, you'll need the 32-bit version.  If you still have trouble then use SysInternals' Process Monitor.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant. Yes this is true but i tried with two version of regasm but not working. :'( i need help please.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have another instance created to that object. If yes you will need to close it first.

Comment: Hi @Gonzalo, thank you for your answer. I dont think there is another instance of the object created but does not work in win32.

Comment: Isn't there another application running that use the same DLL? I had a similar issue with Outlook.exe in 64bit windows. I had to close outlook first before i could create the object in my code.

Comment: No because this DLL its created by me. I dont understand why dont work in win64. In win32 works perfect.